# Поиск индексов пересекающихся многомерных списков

Tags: python, pandas

Строго задача звучит следующим образом.

Для каждой пары `(k, v)` из списка (или фрейма данных) `B` необходимо найти индекс `v`-того вхождения числа `k` в список `A`.

У меня имеется список с огромным количеством значений, где имеются повторяющиеся.

Например

```
A = (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2...)
```

И также имеется сложный список (или `df` - это не особенно важно) с необходимыми значениями. Например:

```
B = (('Значение1',('Порядковые индексы в рамках этого значения1'),  
     ('Значение2',('Порядковые индексы в рамках этого значения2'))
```

Пример для B ниже.

Нужно получить индексы вот такого сложного пересечения в массиве `A`.

Для примера операция должна делать следующее:

```
A = (1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4)

B =
    С1  С2  
0   1   0   
1   1   1   
2   1   2   
3   3   1   
4   3   2
5   3   3   

c=operation(A,B)
# В итоге должно получиться следующее
c= (0,1,2,8,9,10)
```

Результат `c` должен быть списком.

Очень важно, что циклы здесь очень нежелательны, так как массив `A` может содержать миллионы точек.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть что B по сути является DataFrame.
В рамках примера выше
B=
[[1,0],
[1,1],
[1,2],
[3,3],
[3,4],
[3,5]]
Я к тому что df в задаче использовать можно и не обязательно строить замысловатые многомерные списки как выше в посте.

Comment: упоминать надо в вопросе, который вы можете редактировать, а не в комментариях к нему.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример данных (чтобы это было похоже на DataFrame) и результат, который вы хотите получить. В текущей формулировке вообще ничего не понятно. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я извиняюсь что так некорректно писал. Если что то все еще не понятно просьба написать в комментариях

Comment: Я правильно понял, что для каждой пары (k, v) из списка (ну или датафрейма) B вы желаете найти индекс v-того вхождения числа k в список A? Если да, то отредактируйте свой вопрос и так там и напишите. Сейчас действительно очень тяжело понять, что вы хотите.

Comment: Теперь стало понятнее как выглядит фрейм B, но все ещё непонятно как вы получили “c” из “A” и “B”

Comment: @EzikBro, да все именно так. Меня беспокоит тот факт что точек может быть очень много - это главное. Циклами решать будет долго

Comment: @MaxU, алгоритм следующий если мыслит в рамках циклов.
1)Берется A
2)Берется отсортированный по первой колонке B
3)По циклу находим как только первый раз попадется в A первое значение (k) в колонке B
4) Аналогичная операция, но в рамках второй колонки B и допсписком из А состоящего только из элемнтов k

Comment: Списки А и B предполагаются упорядоченными? Сколько различных значение может быть в списке A?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, оба списка не упорядочены. Упорядочены только блоки в C2 при одном k. В списке A может быть в районе 10^4 уникальный значений

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я доработаю ответ [EzikBro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266465/416121) чтобы он лучше использовал особенности Python.

Комбинацию `range(len(A))` почти всегда можно переписать через `enumerate(A)`.

Комбинация `if k not in d: d[k] = ...` заменяется на `d.setdefault(k, ...)`.

```
def retrieve(a, b):
    indices = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(a):
        indices.setdefault(v, []).append(i)
    return [indices[v][j] for v, j in b]

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
b = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]

print(retrieve(a, b))
```

> [0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10]

Если в списке `b` есть значения которых нет в `a`, то их можно пропустить:

```
    ...
    return [indices[v][j] for v, j in b if v in indices]
```

Сложность линейная (`O(|a| + |b|)`), её в данной задаче не улучшить. Константу улучшить можно. Мои измерения показывают что при длине `a` `10^7` и `b` `10^4` код работает меньше трёх секунд.

Решение [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266481/416121) имеет лучшую константу но худшую сложность: `O(|a||b|)`. На тех же размерах оно медленнее - семь секунд. Кроме того оно предполагает что оба списка упорядочены.

Comment: а как справляться с тем что в B могут быть значения, которых нет в A? Ну то есть их нужно пропускать. Но код это не учитывает.

Comment: Добавил в ответ обработку отсутствия значения.

Comment: Все работает прекрасно. Спасибо больше за помощь.

Answer (score 7):

С pandas я вам особо не помогу, но на чистом питоне можно сделать так:

```
A = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4]
B = [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]]

indexes = {}
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] not in indexes:
        indexes[A[i]] = []
    indexes[A[i]].append(i)

C = [indexes[k][v] for k, v in B]
# [0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10]
```

По сути, оно работает примерно за `O(len(A) + len(B))`, так что особо долго на списках длины ~10^6-10^7 работать не будет. Если у вас большИе размеры или очень важна производительность, то действительно нужно использовать pandas и ему подобные.

Comment: это действительно решение задачи в рамках задачи в примерах. Я пока оставлю ваш пример решения так как возможно кто-то сможет предложить вариант с ```pandas```

Comment: Конкретно сейчас у меня датасет из 10^7 для A и 10^4 для B. Я протестирую в ближайший день и отпишусь как что работает. Возможно вашего варианта решения хватит.

Answer (score 5):

Вот полувекторизированное решение в стиле Pandas и Numpy:

```
A = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4])

res = np.concatenate([(A==k).argmax() + v["C2"] for k,v in B.groupby("C1")])
```

результат:

```
In [66]: res
Out[66]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: я проведу анализ по временам и отпишусь в ближайшие дни. Ваше решение, конечно, более изящное. Спасибо вам тоже.